# Inject event with adb in android

Tags: android, bash, adb

I need to fill form automatically in android. So I inject events and automatize data from a database. The thing is when I click submit, I don't know how to wait for the operation to complete. The only thing I can do is pause the system for a period of time... Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ProgressDialog` to keep the app `"active"` while the operation is in progress.

Comment: I'm not programming in Java, I'm Using Bash. Is there a way to display ProgressDialog with adb???

Comment: Oh i see...Then i suggest you edit your tags to include `Bash` if you want the right people to find your question.That said,i don't know much about Bash, but i think you should try and find out if `ProgressDialog` works with `Bash` rather than `adb`.